# SignalR connection (hub proxy) lifetime

Tags: connection, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

What is best practice for connecting clients to SignalR hub? In client, is it better to keep connection (hub proxy) somewhere, or is it better to create connection (hub proxy) for each hub method call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimal way to go is to keep just a single connection for all method calls. Every new connection you open will waste network resources and processing, as SignalR needs to keep a live connection with the server for each connection. That means battery drain on mobile devices and more server workload.

**[UPDATE]**

After reading @alex-dresko answer I realized my answer needs some clarification.
It doesn´t matter how many proxies you create under the same connection, it won´t change performance:

```
hubConnection = new HubConnection(BASE_ADDRESS);

var chatProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("chatHub");
var otherProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("otherHub");  
var nProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("nHub");
```

However, you are asking if

> is it better to keep connection (hub proxy) somewhere

Well, connection is one thing (`HubConnection`) and the proxy is another thing.
New connections will open a new bridge between the client and the server, so creating and persisting a single connection globally in your app makes sense. Then you can reuse the very same connection to create as many proxies as you want.

You can easily test this scenario. Create a console app that creates a connection and 2 proxy hubs. Then create 2 connections and 1 hub on each one and check the signalr logs...

Comment: This is the answer that I needed. I am doing it exactly this way even when it is not mobile/web application, but desktop application.

Answer (score 3):

Per https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#multiplehubs

> There is no performance difference for multiple Hubs compared to
>   defining all Hub functionality in a single class.

Whether or not you use multiple hubs is simply a matter of deciding how you want to logically organize your code. Standard OOP practices apply here.

Later in the same documentation...

> If you need to use the context multiple-times in a long-lived object,
>   get the reference once and save it rather than getting it again each
>   time. Getting the context once ensures that SignalR sends messages to
>   clients in the same sequence in which your Hub methods make client
>   method invocations.  For a tutorial that shows how to use the SignalR
>   context for a Hub, see Server Broadcast with ASP.NET SignalR.

...not sure if that last bit is relevant to what you're asking, but it's good to know as you plan your signalr architecture.